# timer issue at getting previous view

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone development. what i am doing is displaying 20 images as grid and each image treat as button,by selecting that image it will be displayed on image view "here what i needed is i using timer to get back to grid but there is [NSCFArray ObjectAtIndex]: index(4) beyond bounds(4) and application terminates" how can i slove this problem pls help me

Comment: Question is far too disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Going on very little information here. My best guess is that your grid is 4x5, and you have inadvertently swapped your "x" and "y" variables, i.e. you are trying to access location [4] in an array that only goes from [0] to [3].